# Trouble installing topojson on Mac OSX

Tags: topojson

Enticed by d3, I'm also working from the "Let's map" tutorial (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) and running into a problem installing topojson with the command npm install -g topojson. I installed homebrew and installed node, and both check. GDAL was installed earlier during a python install, version 1.10.0.

Here's some of the error log (I hope the relevant part):

> 44 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ] 45 error Error: EACCES,
>   mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson' 45 error  { [Error:
>   EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson'] 45 error
>   errno: 3, 45 error   code: 'EACCES', 45 error   path:
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson', 45 error   fstream_type:
>   'Directory', 45 error   fstream_path:
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson', 45 error   fstream_class:
>   'DirWriter', 45 error   fstream_stack: 45 error    [
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
>   45 error
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
>   45 error      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }

I've looked through discussions of people having 'similar' problems, but nothing seems to explicitly refer to this problem. I also checked the owner and permissions of the /usr/local/lib/node_modules directory and see they are fine, but the owner is 24561. Not sure if that's correct, it looks odd to me.

Thanks in advance for help!
Francis

Answer (score 3):

/usr/local/lib is owned by root on my system and /usr/local/lib/node_modules is also owned by 24561.

Isaacs seems to have the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/444567/what-is-user-owner-24561) to who 24561 is.

Have you tried `sudo npm install -g topojson`?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I don't (never did either) have the root password for this mac.

Comment: I found this information/instructions to set the root password: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: I found this information/instructions to set the root password: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US. Then switched to root and ran npm. The install ran without errors, but which topojson returns nothing. I checked the directory tree and found this (before stopping...): /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/d3/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules Does that seem right? Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean topojson returns nothing? When you run topojson in the terminal what happens?

Comment: Sorry, when I run the command 'code'which topojson'code' I don't get the path to the file.

Comment: The executable should have been installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/bin/topojson with a link in /usr/local/bin. Can you verify these exist? ls /usr/local/bin/topojson

Comment: Also make sure /usr/local/bin is in your path. echo $PATH

Comment: Check for the executable and $PATH. The $PATH contains /usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framewowrk/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin There's no /usr/local/bin/topojson directory. /usr/local/bin/ is the last directory in that tree.